# mplot3d - How do I display minor ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I display (turn on) minor ticks on a 3D surface plot using mplot3d / axes3d graph?

I can define the major tickmark locations using:

```
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
```

Similarly, I'm guessing I can define the the minor ticks using:

```
ax.w_zaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
```

This appears to define the minor tick locators but doesn't actually turn them on in my plot. How do I turn the minorticks on in my axes3D?

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, minor tick marks aren't fully implemented in mplot3d. The place I'm looking at in the matplotlib code is `Your_Python_Lib_site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axis3d.py` in the `draw()` function. I see only the code to draw the major tick marks, not the minor ones. It seems like it wouldn't be all that hard to modify the code to make it draw the minor tick marks too. I wonder if the matplotlib people even know that the minor tick marks don't work in mplot3d.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That would make sense as to why they don't seem to work on my plots. It's a real shame as minor ticks would be really useful! Perhaps they'll implement it in a future release?

Comment: I was breaking my head with the same thing, until I found this post. Anyone knows if this has been addressed?

Comment: @Arraval I'm dealing with the same issue right now. 

Using the import `import matplotlib.ticker as ticker`, the 2-d case can work as `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())` and `ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())`. Doing the same in 3-d and adding `ax.zaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())` does not work (even for the x- and y- axes). [This issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14980) is the most recent thing that seems relevant. It's only been ~10 years since this question was posted to SO ...

Comment: @Arraval this functionality has now been added. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66789846/9067615).

Answer (score 2):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#d-axes-now-support-minor-ticks) this can be done by setting `minor=True` in:

```
ax.set_xticks(minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(minor=True)
ax.set_zticks(minor=True)
```